# Send Contact Form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send the order form of my website in email. it is working fine but the problem is that i receive the whole information in just one single line. I want to have a line break after every field. my code is:

```
<?php
($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'info@mysite.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Website order form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Adress: ".nl2br($_POST["address"]).""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "product: ".nl2br($_POST["product"])."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "phone: ".nl2br($_POST["phone"])."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "quantity: ".nl2br($_POST["quantity"])."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
window.location='index.html'</script>";
   exit;  

?>
```

Kindly guide me where i am wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to add line breaks ... the character should be "\n" and you can add that where you need in your message body.

Comment: Add \n to the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do use `\r\n` if you use Content-type : **text/plain**
Or `<br/>` if you use **Html**

```
<?php
($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'info@mysite.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Website order form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Adress: ".nl2br($_POST["address"])."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "product: ".nl2br($_POST["product"])."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "phone: ".nl2br($_POST["phone"])."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "quantity: ".nl2br($_POST["quantity"])."";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
window.location='index.html'</script>";
   exit;  

?>
```

Comment: damn , u were 35 secs quicker xP